# Django Redis. Добавление списка словарей в хранилище

Tags: python-3.x, django, redis

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть вопрос:

```
from django_redis import get_redis_connection

redis = get_redis_connection("default")

ls = [{'foo': 15, 'bar': 16}, {'foo': 78, 'bar': 0}, {'foo': 49, 'bar': 7}, {'foo': 1, 'bar': 5}]
for item in ls:
    #TODO: append to redis
    ...
```

Как по-элементно добавить такую структуру в redis?
Чтобы результат хранился в виде:

```
'some_key': [{'foo': 15, 'bar': 16}, {'foo': 78, 'bar': 0}, {'foo': 49, 'bar': 7}, {'foo': 1, 'bar': 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, можно просто записать json. Не подумал сразу.

```
import json
from django_redis import get_redis_connection

redis = get_redis_connection("default")

ls = [{'foo': 15, 'bar': 16}, {'foo': 78, 'bar': 0}, {'foo': 49, 'bar': 7}, {'foo': 1, 'bar': 5}]
for item in ls:
    redis.lpush('some_key', json.dumps(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно по-элементно:

```
redis.set('some_key', ls)
```

Comment: Я все это понимаю, но в моем случае нужно по одному элементу записывать